# Mac-AVAudioRecorder Select Microphone

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, core-audio, avaudiorecorder

In an Application I record audio from the microphone using AVAudioRecorder. I would like the user to be able to choose the microphone/recording settings they want to use, not just use the defaults from system preferences. However, I have not found any way to do this using AVAudioRecorder. Is it possible to do this using AVAudioRecorder, and if not, could I use Core Audio or something else to do this? If so, how would I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You may need to go a bit more low level than AVAudioRecorder, which probably gets its settings & inputs from whatever the user has specified as the defaults in the "Sound" system preference pane.

Perhaps you could consider trying some of the AVCapture* classes?

You can specify a different audio input via the ["`AVCaptureDeviceInput`" class](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureDeviceInput_Class/), and there's some nice sample code available from Apple including [AVRecorder](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/AVRecorder/).